# Printer naming in Juno

Tags: release-juno, printer

I've used Freya, Loki and now Juno. From memory, it was the same with each. Whenever I install a new printer through the GUI, the printer name (in print dialogs) shows as something non-descriptive such as "LPD_LPR_Host_or_Printer", rather than the description I give it (which in my case would be something like "MFC-L2750".
I only have one printer at home, but would still like to see a proper name (that I give it) rather than what it is now. 
For the moment I use Cups to setup printers, as that allows me to specify a pretty name, but its something I would expect to be able to do in the System printer setup UI.

I guess it's not so much a question as a comment. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System Settings` > `Printers`, then click your printer's `Settings and Supplies` tab. There, in the `Description` field, you can rename your printer to whatever you want.

Comment: No, that sets the printer description, not the actual printer name that shows in printer dialogs.

Comment: Ah, get it :) Have you tried this trick: https://askubuntu.com/a/954914

Comment: While that would work, it's similar to what I do now, access cups through the browser and add the printer that way. But that's not the Elementary way though. It's not something anyone could do. I should be able to specify the printername in the printer setup dialog. (or the queuename as cups calls it). The printer setup dialog should ask for both the queuename and the description.

Comment: Sure, that's how it should be done in a mature OS. Why don't you file a feature request for that functionality @ https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-printers/issues ?

Comment: Thank you for posting that link to github. I couldn't find it earlier. This particular issue apparently has already been raised back in Nov 2018, I've just commented on it to put my 'weight' behind it.